# How to isolate specific terms in a maxima equality

Tags: math, symbolic-math, maxima, equation-solving, wxmaxima

I perform some calculations with maxima and I would like to isolate a specific part of an expression at the left hand side of the equality and push the rest to the right hand side.

For an example I would like to isolate `x^2+y^2` in the following expression :

```
(%i1)   expand((x-x1)^2 + (y-y1 )^2 = r1^2);
(%o1)   y1^2-2*y*y1+y^2+x1^2-2*x*x1+x^2=r1^2
```

and I would like to have :

```
(%o1)   y^2+x^2=r1^2+2*x*x1-x1^2+2*y*y1-y1^2
```

I thought using `algsys` to do that but it's clearly not the right function :

```
(%i3)   algsys ([expand((x-x1)^2 + (y-y1 )^2 = r1^2)], [x^2+y^2]);
(%o3)   []

(%i4)   algsys ([expand((x-x1)^2 + (y-y1 )^2 = r1^2)], [x]);
(%o4)   [[x=sqrt(-y1^2+2*y*y1-y^2+r1^2)+x1],[x=x1-sqrt(-y1^2+2*y*y1-y^2+r1^2)]]
```

**Do you know how to isolate specific terms in a expression with maxima ?**

Comment: Couple of ideas. Try `lhs` and `rhs` to get left and right hand sides. Also, `+` distributes over `=`, so adding something to an equation adds that stuff to both sides. E.g. `%o1 - rhs(%o1) - (x^2 + y^2)`, maybe that helps.